# Pandas apply function with vector argument

Tags: python, pandas

Sample DF:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [2, 4, 8, 0],
                   'num_wings': [2, 0, 0, 0],
                   'num_specimen_seen': [10, 2, 1, 8]},
                  index=['falcon', 'dog', 'spider', 'fish'])
```

I have vector (pd.Series) which length is equal to number of columns in df:

```
x_add = pd.Series([1,2,3])
```

I would like to add element-wise `x_add` to every column of df (add 1 to first column, 2 to second etc...). Something like tihs (these code doesn't work):

```
def my_sum(series, x):
    y = x + 3 * 5
    z = x - 5 + 8
    series = series + 1 + z + x
    return series
x_vector = [1, 2 ,3]
df.apply(lambda x: my_sum(x, x_vector), axis=1)
```

It would be great if you can simultaneously write a solution to execute `apply` in parallel.

**Hope last edit**

REal function I want to use:

```
import pandas as pd
from mlfinlab.features.fracdiff import frac_diff_ffd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [2, 4, 8, 0, 8, 9, 7, 7, 5000, 60000],
                   'col2': [2, 0, 0, 0, 200, 4400, 544560, 2564, 543, 454]})


argument_vector = [1, 2]
df.apply(lambda x: frac_diff_ffd(x, argument_vector))
```

Comment: For your solution to work, you're missing `axis=1` , `df.apply(lambda x: x + x_add,axis=1)` but as below ans states, you dont need apply for this - pandas has a builtin

Comment: can you post the expected output for the edited function?

Comment: @anky_p1, I want to make nonstationary time series stationary, but wanted to simplify it with some function. I have added code with the real function I want to use. The whole point its that argument to lambda function have multiple values, and every element have to ber applied on column in df.

Comment: Sorry I am not able to use that lib. You could have made your example better rather than  iterative discussions. Hope someone can help

Comment: I changed the code last time. Simple solutin and real problem.

Answer (score 3):

Simply,

```
>>> df + x_add.values

        num_legs  num_wings  num_specimen_seen
falcon         3          4                 13
dog            5          2                  5
spider         9          2                  4
fish           1          2                 11
```

For `apply`:

```
>>> df.apply(lambda x: x + x_add.values, axis=1)

        num_legs  num_wings  num_specimen_seen
falcon         3          4                 13
dog            5          2                  5
spider         9          2                  4
fish           1          2                 11
```

According to edit:

```
def my_sum(series, x):
    return series + x

my_sum(df.iloc[0], 2)

x_vector = [1, 2 ,3]
df.apply(lambda x: my_sum(x, x_vector), axis=1)
```

BTW, there is already function that does this for you:

```
from operator import add
df.apply(lambda x: add(x, x_vector), axis=1)
```

Comment: your solutions are ok, but my case is a little different. It seems I made a question too simple. I have changed code again.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html):

```
df.add(pd.Series([1,2,3]).values)
```

with `apply`:

```
df.apply(lambda row: row.add(x_add.values), axis=1)
```

---

```
        num_legs  num_wings  num_specimen_seen
falcon         3          4                 13
dog            5          2                  5
spider         9          2                  4
fish           1          2                 11
```

using `.values` ​​is necessary as long as the `x_add` **index** is not `columns` of the dataframe

**EDIT**

```
x_vector = [1, 2 ,3]
df.apply(lambda row: my_sum(row, x_vector), axis=1)
```

Comment: Ok, that's true, but my real function is more complex. It's not an addition (I put it for simplicity). I would like to see the solution with `apply`. The main problem is that the argument is a vector, not a scalar

Comment: Then you need `.apply` with `axis=1`

Comment: I change the code, I hope now is more clear what I want.

Comment: your solutions are ok, but my case is a little different. It seems I made a question too simple. I have changed code again.